# 'Not Found' status for grade value api call

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am trying to get the grade values for a specific user by using the api call,

/d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/(gradeObjectId)/values/(userId). But it returns 'Not Found' status as response. In front end, I can see that the course is completed and grade has been assigned to that particular user. But not sure, why i am not able to get it through valence.

What does this status means? Is it like valence could not find grade values for that particular user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A number of things are possible:

- You haven't correctly provided IDs to specify the Org Unit (course), the particular grade object (line item in the gradebook), or user
- The calling user making this API call does not have permission to use this call to see the grade value

For example, if your calling user context is a *student user* (i.e. the person to whom the grade is assigned), then it's likely that this user will not have permission to issue the call you describe -- typically, the call you refer to is intended for use by administrative users.

When you want a calling user to retrieve "their own" grades, you should use the 'my grades' family of calls instead. In particular you might want the call to [fetch back "my grade" for a particular grade object](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-grades-%28gradeObjectId%29-values-myGradeValue) here.

Additionally, note that the APIs to fetch back final grade values are separate from the calls to get grade values for other grade objects, and also the final *calculated* grade value isn't accessible through the API, only the final *adjusted* grade value (and even then, only when the final grade is "released").